# Is this question in-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic

Would it be in-topic to ask if, given the current shortage of MacBooks, I should buy a MacBook Pro 14'' with M1 Pro, or wait until the M2 comes out? I'm not interested in gaming, but I want to train ML models.

Answer (score 7):

Primarily and entirely opinion based - and hopefully unlikely to be helpful to anyone else in the future (Cause hardware shortages suck). Its likely to get closed.